# Dynamic dropdown produces weird results

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-select

I have the following code that I am trying to use to dynamically populate a dropdownlist from SQL Server database.

```
 <select name="BidType" class="inputstandard">
 <option value=""></option>

 <?
     $tsql = mysql_query('SELECT BidID, BidType FROM BidTypes ORDER BY BidID ASC')
     $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
     if( $stmt === false )
     {
      echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
     }
      while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
       echo '<option value="' . $row['BidID'] . '" name="' . $row['BidType']. '">' . $row['BidType']. '</option>';
     }
  ?>

 </select>
```

When I run it, rather than populate dropdown with data from database, it just shows the following: **. $row['BidType'].**

Any ideas?

Sorry if the code is too elementary. I am learning.
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't merge SQL Server functions `sqlsrv_query` with MySql functions `mysql_query`

Try with this:

```
 <select name="BidType" class="inputstandard">
 <option value=""></option>

 <?

mysql_connect("localhost", "your_user", "your_pass");
mysql_select_db("your_bd");

     $tsql = mysql_query('SELECT BidID, BidType FROM BidTypes ORDER BY BidID ASC')
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tsql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
       echo '<option value="' . $row['BidID'] . '" name="' . $row['BidType']. '">' . $row['BidType']. '</option>';
     }
  ?>

 </select>
```

Comment: Thank you but your solution is in mysql and we would like it in SQL Server.

Now, it shows blank.

Comment: Ok it is working now. i changed it back to my original code but with slight adjustment per your comment.

`$tsql = "SELECT ....";`

Thank you very much